Cannot Save the new Category in magento 2.4.7-p2
When I saved the new category with Input field Category Name,It saved the new category.NO ISSUE..
But When I tried to save the new category with the Content > Category Image and then It throws the issue:
main.CRITICAL: Error: Call to a member function getStore() on null in /var/www/html/protecta/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Category/Attribute/Backend/Image.php:142
[internal function]: Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Attribute\Backend\Image->beforeSave()
#1 /var/www/html/protecta/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/AbstractEntity.php(695): call_user_func_array()
#2 /var/www/html/protecta/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/AbstractEntity.php(1858): Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\AbstractEntity->walkAttributes()
#3 /var/www/html/protecta/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Category.php(290): Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\AbstractEntity->_beforeSave()
#4 /var/www/html/protecta/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/AbstractEntity.php(1978): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category->_beforeSave()
#5 /var/www/html/protecta/vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/Observer/BeforeEntitySave.php(36): Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\AbstractEntity->beforeSave()
#6 /var/www/html/protecta/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(88): Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Observer\BeforeEntitySave->execute()
#7 /var/www/html/protecta/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(74): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->_callObserverMethod()
#8 /var/www/html/protecta/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->dispatch()
#9 /var/www/html/protecta/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault\Interceptor->___callParent()
#10 /var/www/html/protecta/vendor/smile/module-debug-toolbar/Plugin/Event/InvokerPlugin.php(45): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#11 /var/www/html/protecta/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Smile\DebugToolbar\Plugin\Event\InvokerPlugin->aroundDispatch()
#12 /var/www/html/protecta/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#13 

